# JMSSerializerBundle: the annotation '@Enum' in property Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue::$strategy was never imported

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Im gettig this error:

> The annotation '@Enum' in property
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue::$strategy was never imported. Did
>   you maybe forget to add a 'use' statement for this annotation?

Im just trying to serialize a paginator object:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);
$serializer = \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($paginator, 'json');
```

These are my composer.json packages installed:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.3             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.4.0             Caching library offering an objec...
doctrine/collections                 v1.2               Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.4.2             Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.1             Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.3.0             Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       v1.0.1             Symfony2 Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle  dev-master 81575a4 Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1             Common String Manipulations with ...
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1             Base library for a lexer that can...
doctrine/migrations                  dev-master 96f838b Database Schema migrations using ...
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.7             Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
gedmo/doctrine-extensions            v2.3.9             Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle      dev-master 2ff8473 Integration of the gedmo/doctrine...
```

Comment: Try to add: use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Enum; in your Entity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a thread on JMSSerializer's Github page: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/380

Passing a non-entity result to Serializer could produce such error.

Basically, you shouldn't pass the paginator to the serializer, you should pass the paginator execution results instead, as serializer doesn't know how to process a `Paginator`.